# Unable to load dynamic html page for the second time in Phonegap Application for Windows Phone 8

Tags: jquery-mobile, windows-phone-8

I am building a phonegap application. IIt works fine for iOS and Android , but in Windows Phone 8, the application does not load the page for the second time. I have a list on Page 1. When I click at each list item,it opens up its details on the second page.

The code of Page 1 is as follows-

```
//Each list item belongs to class 'stores-list'
$(document).on("click", '.stores-list', function() {

    if (storage.getDataForKey('storeDetails') != null) {
        storage.clearData('storeDetails');
    }
    storage.setDataForKey('storeDetails', stores[$(this).index()]);
    $.mobile.changePage('store-details.html', {
        transition: 'slide',
       // data: stores[$(this).index()],
    });
});
```

The code of Page 2 is as follows-

```
$(document).on("pagebeforecreate", '#store-details', function () {
    var storeDetailsQuery = storage.getDataForKey('storeDetails');
    displaystoredetailsdata(storeDetailsQuery);
});

function displaystoredetailsdata(data1) {
    var htmlstoredetails = "";
    htmlstoredetails += '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a">Store Name</div><div class="ui-block-b">';
    htmlstoredetails += '' + data1.storeName + '</div></div>';

    htmlstoredetails += '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a">Type</div><div class="ui-block-b">';
    htmlstoredetails += '' + data1.storeType + '</div></div>';

    htmlstoredetails += '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a">Mobile</div><div class="ui-block-b">';
    htmlstoredetails += '<a href="tel:' + data1.mobile + '">' + data1.mobile + '</a></div></div>';

    htmlstoredetails += '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a">Address</div><div class="ui-block-b">';
    htmlstoredetails += '' + data1.address + ', ' + data1.city + ' - ' + data1.pin + '</div></div>';

    htmlstoredetails += '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a">Week Off</div><div class="ui-block-b">';
    htmlstoredetails += '' + data1.weekOff + '</div></div>';

    htmlstoredetails += '<div class="ui-grid-a"><div class="ui-block-a">Timings</div><div class="ui-block-b">';
    htmlstoredetails += '' + data1.timings + '</div></div>';
    $('#page-store-details-display').html(htmlstoredetails);
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that when I click on a list item , it opens up the next page and display the details. But when for the second time, if I click on any list item, it redirects to other page and even create correct dynamic html, but page is not displayed for any reason that I am not able to get. (I also tried firing "pageshow" event. It executed for the first time. But didnot fire when I clicked any list item the second time.)

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $.mobile.changePage uses the jQuery Mobile AJAX functionality, that happen only in SPA (Single Page Application) design, you are using multipage application so you need to use window.location.href="store-details.html".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, it didnot help either. I am working on my other pages with the same method. It is working fine there. And if the problem had been because of $.mobile.changePage() , it would have not fired the "pagebeforecreate" event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution to my question. Actually localStorage when was getting cleared,it raised an unexpected event handling. So instead of clearing the storage, I simply updated the value of key.